# <urlopen error [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it>

Tags: python, sockets, openstreetmap, geopy, nominatim

I am using geopy to normalize some addresses but when I try to run this code I am getting an error.

> urlopen error [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the
>   target machine actively refused it>

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim()
rawAddress = '151 MCKINLEY AVE CAMP MEEKER CA 95419'
location = geolocator.geocode(rawAddress, timeout=15)
print location.address
```

There are bunch of addresses which I need to normalize but I am not able to resolve this error. Could anyone help me? 
My firewall and antivirus are both off. I have already gone through bunch of questions in stack overflow but none is helpful.

Comment: Whichever machine you are trying to connect to said **no** emphatically. Find out which host you are trying to connect to.

Comment: The program was running smoothly since morning and then error started coming.

Comment: That doesn't change the validity of @AlG's advice: whatever machine you are trying to connect to is no longer listening.

Comment: Al and Rob both are right. You probably got rate-limited or banned if you were trying to scrape a "bunch of addresses", per the [Nominatim usage policy](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim#Usage_Policy).

Comment: I just tried to run the same script from a different computer but still the same error. I pretty sure they might have restricted me for a day or banned me but running the same script in a different PC also didn't work. Any comments?

Comment: Does this other computer has the same IP address? Or the same user agent? Anyway, as already explained you have to comply with the usage policy of the Nominatim instance you are using. Or install your own instance.

Comment: @scai It is working now :)

Comment: @scai could you share any documents for installing open street server on windows? Any material will be helpful

Comment: @RakeshRanjanSukla See [Nominatim/Installation](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Installation) in the OSM Wiki.